# Is it possible to use https with a Tang Network Bound Disk Encryption server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel7, rhel8, rocky-linux

Is it possible to use https with a Tang Network Bound Disk Encryption (NBDE) server?

Redhat's documentation casually says this is possible, but I can't find any examples of this anywhere and the source code leaves me to believe otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you put https to http reverse proxy in front of it and I believe this is what documentation ment here. I don't think tang code natively supports https.